# Sending emails using PHP's send() and the SPF issues

Tags: php, email, dns, spf

I have a complicated question about sending emails..

First I have a domain: mydomain.com
I also have a "Domain mailbox", something like Google's Business mail service -- so I set the MX record to mxdomain.xxx.com

I see that setting a txt record for SPF is good for my email sending therefore I added one like "v=spf1 include:spf.mail.xxx.com ~all" with "@".

Then question comes..

1. I found there are already two txt records:

   **@**        v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all    1 Hour

   **admin**    v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all    1 Hour

Should I delete them and why..?

2. What are the difference between "@" and "admin"...??
3. On my website mydomain.com, I have a contact form, which will send automatical emails to me and to the one who fills the form. The form simply uses PHP's send() function, not using SMTP. 
   In my understanding, I should set two SPF record for my "domain-mailbox" and the web form, am I correct? Then how to do that? Or what you guys deal with it?

---

These questions are actually very difficult since they relate to different things.. When I google them, people just give unclear solutions and they can't really explain their answers. If there are repeated answers on stackflow please tell me -- I really didn't find..

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You may wish to break your questions up into smaller questions. That would help people to answer them.

Comment: Right now this question is impossibly broad... there are way too many things to answer.  You'll get a much better response if you split them up.